# Wizard screens filtering data based on other selections

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, database, database-design

***Scenario:***

I have a wizard screen which has several steps. One of the steps being a questionnaire. The questions displayed in this screen can be standard or dynamic. By dynamic I mean, they will be based on selection in the previous steps. The question may be mandatory/optional or visible/invisible based on selections from other steps.

***Current System:***

The current system I have is that each step's data is stored in its respective table(s) and I have a filter and criteria table for each of the tables per step. I have a configuration screen for each step where the filter criteria selection happens and the wizard step based on the filters displays/hides the fields or makes them mandatory/optional.

***Problem:***

I believe by doing this the above way I have too many tables and it gets a little cluttered if any more new steps are added (which can be a requirement for future). The whole thing also I feel is a bit convoluted because of the number of filters/criteria items I have to deal with. Is there a better way of achieving this functionality?

Please suggest.

Comment: Are you asking about the entire wizard or just the questionnaire?

Comment: just the questionnaire, entire wizard is fine, just the filtering of questions based on other selections in other tabs.

Comment: Can you share you current database design?

Comment: @ZoharPeled I will try my best to share the db design.